# Passing parameter to a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a SQL query and that works, but the stored procedure is not working when I try with parameters.

Example :

```
select * 
from Table1 
where Name = 'BEST People'     // this works

// this does not show any rows
declare @Name nvarchar(128)
set @Name= 'BEST People'

select * 
from Table1 
where Name = @Name
```

Even when I try with a stored procedure, it does not work.

Comment: Is `Name` defined as a `VARCHAR` or as `NVARCHAR`

Comment: In the design, it is defined as nvarchar(128).

Comment: what do you mean by it does not work? it doesnt return any rows? or it errors out????

Comment: It does not return any rows

Comment: I would check your Table1 values for hidden characters. [Online Toolz](http://string.online-toolz.com/tools/string-functions.php#string-hidden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the string to `NVARCHAR`:

```
declare @Name nvarchar(128)
set @Name= N'BEST People'
select * from Table1 where Name = @Name
```

Without the `N` it will be a `VARCHAR`

Comment: Do you get any rows with `LIKE`:
select * from Table1 where Name LIKE '%'+ @Name+'%'

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your column collation String Comparison Work 
Specify Your Question Like This

[image]

Here's how you would check your column collation:

```
DECLARE @TableId INT
SELECT @TableId=id FROM sys.sysobjects
    WHERE xtype='U' AND name='Table1';  --Your table name here
SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.columns
    WHERE object_id=@TableId AND name=N'Name';  --Your column name here
```

[View Collation Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230914.aspx#TsqlProcedure)